# how to identify the visible keyboard is whether numberpad or default keyboard?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How can one identify if the visible keyboard is a numberpad or the default keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

You should ask the UITextInputTraits for its keyboardType-propery. Both UITextField and UITextView implements this protocol.

An example would be:

```
if(myTextField.keyboardType == UIKeyboardTypeURL) {
    // do something if it wants URLs
}
```

Check [the documentations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextInputTraits) for more.